# Programming library for (fast) signature based matching?

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

I've been given an assignment to build an application that will perform signature based matching on some network traffic (at layer 7). Matching will be performed in real-time and it needs to be fast in order for the system to keep it's responsiveness at all times.

At first I thought about using regular expressions as signatures and pcre as a library for matching. But it seems this is too slow. There will be a few thousand signatures for matching.

Since I don't have a lot of experience in signature based content matching I am asking:

1. Should I use regular expressions as signatures and find some faster library?
2. Is there any other library (free or commercial) for signature based matching that is fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build an efficient RE matcher, one compiles it into a finite state machine with accept and not-accept states.

When you have more than one RE, you can easily form their disjunction, and compile that into an FSA, with not-accept states, and states marked according to which RE accepted.

So with a few thousand REs, you compute one huge disjunction and build the FSA for that set.

Most standard lexing engines (e.g., FLEX) do exactly this, using one RE per token, and will tell you which token.   So you ought to be able to use FLEX as a starting place.